# Select statement in kdb not working

Tags: select, kdb

I have a problem with a select statement in KDB giving strange results. The data is OPRA data. i.e. listed options exchange data. The object of the query is to give the last ASK_PRICE for a specific `EXERCISE_PRICE` and `EXERCISE_DATE` in 10 minute intervals. The table only has 1 day in it. So the statement looks like (and gives empty results):

```
select
    last ASK_PRICE by 10 xbar TRADE_TIME.minute 
from
    trade
where
    EXERCISE_PRICE=12 and EXPIRATION_DATE=2014.01.18
```

If I alter the statement to look like to see if there is data that might fit the query, I tried:

```
select
    last ASK_PRICE,EXERCISE_PRICE by 10 xbar TRADE_TIME.minute
from
    trade
where
    EXERCISE_PRICE>12 and EXPIRATION_DATE=2014.01.18
```

I get the following results with an `EXERCISE_PRICE` of 12 showing up in the results, but also with values of less than 12 as well. Results are truncated:

```
minute  ASK_PRICE EXERCISE_PRICE (the table header)

09:50   6.2 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 13 14 14 14 14 14 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 17 17 17 10 10
```

Please note in the result the `ASK_PRICE` is 6.2 and the rest of the values are the `EXERCISE_PRICE`. That is, all the `EXERCISE_PRICE` values for the time period 09:50.

So it's really not clear why when I specify >12 that I get values below 12. When I specify = 12, I get nothing.

The Meta information on the table gives the column `EXERCISE_PRICE` as type f, the column `EXERCISE_DATE` as d, the column `TRADE_TIME` as t and the `ASK_PRICE` as f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There looks to be a hidden error in your query. 
When you use **and** in a where clause it is the equivalent to running:

```
"where EXERCISE_PRICE>(12 and EXPIRATION_DATE=2014.01.18)"
```

This is because kdb+ evaluates right to left - try using `,` (comma) to separate your where conditions.

```
q)select last ASK_PRICE,EXERCISE_PRICE by 10 xbar TRADE_TIME.minute from trade where EXERCISE_PRICE>12 , EXPIRATION_DATE=2014.01.18
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked. I spent a lot of time scratching my head about this.

Comment: If the answer satisfied your question, please mark it as accepted (and you might also upvote) to help other people find it.